# How to import packages installed with PIP3 in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.5

I have Python 3.5 installed and whenever I call a package installed with pip3 I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\python3.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have added the proper path to environment variables but I can't seem to get python to find the packages. Others who face this problem are mostly on Mac and their solution is to add the path to the environmental variables.

Here are my path variables:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;
C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32";
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages";
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts"
```

I am not using a virtual environment.
If I'm using Idle, I can successfully import packages but calling them from the command line produces the error.  Using the full path in the command line works but calling the package without the full path doesn't

```
python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts\django-admin.py" startproject superlists
```

works but

```
python django-admin.py startproject superlists
```

does not

Comment: please show your code

Comment: django-admin.py is a function that comes packaged with django.  I'm just trying to create a new Django project and start the server.

Comment: `Path` is only used to find a file to run. It's how `python` is found. Handling the rest of the command line is up to the process. Given an unqualified script name, Python opens it relative to the working directory. It doesn't search `Path` for a match or even in its known "Scripts" and --user "Scripts" directories. To search for and run a script in a `Path` directory, run the script directly, not `python`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your PATH to contain the Scripts folder, you're right, you shouldn't have to specify the full path.  I think your problems are actually coming from elsewhere:

1. when your run `django-admin.py`, it should be just `django-admin.py`, not `python django-admin.py`
2. when you run `python manage.py something`, you should make sure you are in the correct directory, so `cd` into your django project directory, the one that contains the actual *manage.py* file.

Comment: This is clearly a step in the right direction, but now I get a new error

`$ python3 manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\site.py", line 72, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\os.py", line 708, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import MutableMapping
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Lib\_collections_abc.py", line 56
    async def _coro(): pass
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Failed to import the site module`